# How to render html in JSX right?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

I have component, and I have string variable with html from props (for example):

```
<b style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px;">Lorem ipsum</b><span style="font-size: 18px;">&nbsp;dolor sit amet</span>
```

how do I render html in JSX right?

```
const Item: React.FC<ItemProps> = (props) => {
  const { item } = props;
  const { title, htmlText} = item;

  return (
    <div className="item">
      <div>{title}</div>

      <div>{htmlText}</div> 
      // it render it as plain text

      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlText }}></div> 
      // it render htmlText as html but I got react warning - 
      // "Dangerous property 'dangerouslySetInnerHTML' found  react/no-danger"!
    </div>
  )
}
```

Is there another way to render html string from props with no warnings?

Comment: From your code, you already have your answer. That's how you do it. But you *shouldn't* do it in 99.999999% of situations, which is why the development version of React warns you not to do it.

Comment: *"...and I have string variable with html from props..."* That's a red flag. Why are you passing around HTML as props? That's an anti-pattern in React.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  I get html string from backend using rest API, and tried to use it as is. So can you give me idea - how I should use it? parse it somehow and rebuild it? just have no idea yet...

Comment: Ideally, you update the backend to send you data you use to build the representation rather than giving you HTML. But if you **have** to accept HTML from the backend and then render it within a React component, `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is how you do that. :-) [There are other ways, but that's probably the most appropriate one for what you describe.] (The warning is only in the dev libraries. The production libraries won't spam your users' consoles with warnings.)